# IE11 - Object doesn't support property or method 'next' - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

The next() method has been used in the following way in multiple Angular services. This is causing issues in IE11, is there an alternate way/method which can be used to replace next().

```
doServiceRequestOCMS(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      var callBackHandler = function (json: any) {
        observer.next(JSON.parse(json));
      };
      var options = {
        cb: callBackHandler,
        readonly: false
      };
      (<any>window).doServiceRequest(data, options);
    });
  }
```

Also, I'm not able to find any polyfills for the .next() method. It is also worth mentioning I'm working in an angular seed project (non-cli) and do not have polyfills natively included. I'm also using gulp as a task runner.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next

Also, is there any substitute for the next() method which can achieve a likewise functionality?

Comment: Try adding in `tsconfig.json` the option `"lib": ["dom.iterable"]`

Comment: The Babel polyfill I use contains a custom generator implementation, so there are alternatives out there if it's not included in angular itsself.

Answer (score 1):

Remove comment in the file polyfills.ts

```
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';
```